# JQuery Location Correct?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

this is my first time using jquery, and i dont think it seems to be working. here is some code...

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function insertComment(comment, assignment, pid){
     alert(comment);
     alert(assignment);
     alert(pid);
     var url = "addComment.php";


    $.post(url, {comment: comment, assignment: assignment, pid: pid}); 
}


</script>
```

heres addComment.php

```
<?php

include ("viewComments.php");


//Connection string to get to database
$host = 'host'; 
$user = 'user'; 
$password = 'pw'; 
$dbh = new mysqli($localhost, $user, $password, "kao17_CS242Portfolio");

//Prpared statement for user inpur, prevent sql-injection attacks
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_Comment (comment, project_title, parent_comment_id) VALUES (? , ? , ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $prevComment, $prevAssignment, $parentID);

$prevAssignment = $_POST['assignment'];
$parentID = $_POST['pid'];
$prevComment = profanityCheck($_POST['comment']);




    $stmt->execute();
 ?>
```

its not doing anything. is there away to alert if it actually went to addComments? or am i just using post wrong (SQL should be right). i know i'm getting the information for the parameter right (alerts) any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: check the firebug/console to see any errors.. any 404?

Comment: Check your browsers console. You should see a request there. On most browser it's the `F12` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a callback function to your call to `$.post`:

```
$.post(url, {comment: comment, assignment: assignment, pid: pid}, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Then in your PHP add `die('OK')` after you execute your SQL statement. If you get `OK` in an alert box when you run `insertComment` then you know the call has been successful and any problem is with your PHP.